# Community user's bumps should be so indicated

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, community-user, front-page

When [the Community user](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/u/-1) bumps an old question, can it be labeled "bumped by Community" on the front page instead of "modified by Community"? This way, those of us who remember the question don't have to check for anonymous suggested edits or the like. Also there isn't any modification happening.

Comment: "Bumped" sounds (to me) a bit too informal for public view, especially on the homepage. Perhaps "furthered" or "advanced" instead? (H/t Roget.)

Comment: @msh210 Mr Community User himself calls it "pok[ing]".

Comment: This has been requested a few times, I need to dig into the technicalities behind this to see if that's still a thing. I should be able to come back this week with a response.

Comment: @TimPost [meta-tag:status-review]?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, I'm putting this on my list to research for our weekly feature call. I'm just fuzzy as to why we never did it, since it's come up more than several times.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247392/please-do-not-lie-that-the-community-user-modified-the-question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm [skeptical that this is a good idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247392/please-do-not-lie-that-the-community-user-modified-the-question/266202#266202), since it would necessarily involve introducing jargon in a context where it would be difficult to explain.

Also... The purpose of bumping isn't to get you to look at the question, so it doesn't particularly matter that you remember it. The purpose is to get you to look at the *answer(s)*. Questions are only bumped when they've gotten answers, and those answers have gotten... Nothing. Neither upvoted nor downvoted. Someone invested time trying to solve a problem and got no feedback; that's usually a bad thing, unless your goal is to get folks to leave. Particularly on smaller sites, where attracting knowledgeable answerers is hard enough at the best of times, it's really important that folks who do try to contribute get some sort of feedback.

That out of the way, we *have* taken some steps to make this less confusing. After [asking for suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279203/how-can-we-make-the-purpose-of-community-bumping-more-obvious), we went with a banner that tries to explain in detail what happened and why:

[image: This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.]

Also, we keep a record of when this happens now, so it's possible to [gauge how effective they are](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/634223/how-effective-are-community-bumps): in the past 365 days, 101 questions have been answered after being bumped, while 250 have had existing answers voted on; in total, bumping has been effective 15% of the time on this site (for comparison, bumping is [7.6% effective on DSP](http://data.stackexchange.com/dsp/query/634223/how-effective-are-community-bumps) and [25.7% effective on Webmasters](http://data.stackexchange.com/webmasters/query/634223/how-effective-are-community-bumps)).